# Java: Reading part of a text file

Tags: java

I'm trying to print out sections of a text file. Right now the text file consists of

```
Jack <ID 123.456>
Doug <ID 231.345>
```

This is what i have so far in terms of code:

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("File.txt"));
    String readBuff = reader.readLine();
    String tempString = "";

    while (readBuff != null) {
        if (tempString.equals("<ID ") && !readBuff.equals(">"))
        {
            tempString = readBuff;
            System.out.println(tempString);
        }
        readBuff = reader.readLine();
    }
    reader.close();
```

I was hoping for this to print out the ID section (i.e. "123.456" and "231.345") of each line but right now it doesn't print anything. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("File.txt"));
BufferedReader br   = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] parts = line.split(" ");
    String theId = parts[2].substring(0, parts[2].length()-1);
    System.out.println(theId);
}

br.close();
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you. Time to look up what substring is :P

Answer (score 0):

Initially, `tempString` will be empty, thus it will never be equal to `<ID`, thus your `tempString` assignment will never happen. Thus, I think that this line: `if (tempString.equals("<ID ") && !readBuff.equals(">"))` must be changed to `if (readBuff.contains("<ID ") && !readBuff.endsWith(">"))`. This should print at least the entire line.

To get it to print the `ID` section, you could simply first `split` on the `<`, this will yield an array of 2 segments: `Jack` and `ID 123.456>`. Once you have that, you can simply remove the last character from the second array item and print the content. This should printout the ID you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Your `if` condition is being false each time,

when you are comparing your Strings `<ID` with `tempString` at that moment `tempString` contains nothing. it is null/Blank.
second condition you are checking `readBuff` with ">" while `readBuff` contains line from txt file `Jack <ID 123.456>`.
you need to change your Logic,

```
if(!readBuff.equals("")){
    System.out.println(readBuff);
}
```